# MySql select by excluding all id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I would like to select data from a table which looks like
ID|FOO|CITY|BAR

there is another table where all data which has been selected yet will be stored so that I get unique results. This table looks like
ID|ID_from_other_table

Now I'm stucking if I either should use a left join or a union? 
Which one is faster and, how can I set this up the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`left join` would be *probably* faster in MySQL rather than other anti-join patterns like `not in` and `not exists`.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_from_other_table
where t2.id is null
```